# How can I tell if a mesh is a plane from a topological point of view?

Tags: geometric-topology

I need to distinguish between meshes that can be topologically transformed to a plane (a triangulated square, for example) and those that can not (a cube or a spherical mesh), and among those toruses.

How would I do that - if the mesh is represented with nodes, edges and the resulting triangles?

Sorry if this is imprecise, newbie, and non-mathematician here.

Comment: Is your mesh clearly coming from a surface? Do you know which edges of the mesh are coming from the boundary?

Comment: No - I have no control over the mesh, it is generated using photogrammetry, so it can be anything

Comment: OK, then take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planarity_testing) and see if any of these algorithms are useful to you.